# remotely start a calculation on a linux machine, detach from it and reattach a day later for the results

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, remote, putty

I am using Windows 10 and I can connect to a Linus Mint System via SSH (I am using puTTY).
There I would like to run a Mathematica notebook, which takes a day or so to run through.
My problem is that whenever my internet connection is lost and I want to reconnect to the Linus Mint System, my calculation is lost and I have to restart it.
Is there a way that the session just keeps running in case I disconnect? Such that I can reconnect to it any time later to see the evaluated notebook?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You may want to look at tools like `screen` or `tmux` on the Linux side, which allow you to do just that: detach from a running shell and reattach later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tmux`. First install `tmux` using the package manager of your OS (`sudo apt install tmux`).

Launch `tmux`:

```
tmux new -s mathmematica
```

Then run your mathematica notebook.

Disconnect from the session by:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then <kbd>D</kbd>

And then logout of the ssh session.

Then the next day, `ssh` to the system, and connect the `tmux` session:

```
tmux attach -t mathmematica
```

Comment: If you cannot install `tmux` (lacking root), you can also use `screen` which might already be installed. Works more or less the same, but the default prefix is `C-a` instead of `C-b`.

Comment: Thanks! Tmux was already installed, which is nice, but now I have another problem: I am using xLaunch to start mathematica after launching tmux (which lags like hell). I can start evaluating the notebook, which is fine. But when I then logout and reconnect to my tmux session I get the following error: Mathematica has received the signal: SIGSEGV and has exited. Any idea what to do or should I post another question? (sorry I am a complete Linux noob)